# How to detect in JavaScript which of 2 buttons called a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and an Ajax form. The form post can be triggered by two different buttons. An `OnBegin` option is used to call a function before the form is posted.

The form is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewCoreCase", "CaseStart", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "newCaseValidate",
        OnSuccess = "newCaseClose"
    }
    , new { id = "CaseStartForm" }
    ))
{
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" id="save-asis" class="btn cancel" formnovalidate>Save</button>
        <button type="submit" id="save-all" class="btn btn-primary" >Validate and save</button>
    </div>
}
```

In the JavaScript function `newCaseValidate` how can I detect which of the two buttons was clicked?

Comment: Why do you need it in javascript? If so, it would be easier to use `$.ajax()` and handle the forms `.submit()` event so that you can just get the event target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on where your `newCaseValidate` is attached to.
If it is attached to the entire form and it is listening for `click` event on the entire form, you can make use of event object that is provided as a first argument to `newCaseValidate` listener, so it would look something like this:

```
function newCaseValidate(evt) {
    var target = evt.target; // target is the actual element that was clicked, in your case one of the buttons

    // check if button element was clicked as your form may have other elements
    if(target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') return;

    // then you make use of button id
    if(target.id === 'save-asis') {
       // do something for save-asis
    }
    else if(target.id === 'save-asis') {
       // do something for save-all
    }
}
```

**Edited**:

Since we know that `newCaseValidate` is not a direct click listener, the following logic should do the trick for you:

Adjust `newCaseValidate` to:

```
        function newCaseValidate(evt) {
            var buttons = evt.target.getElementsByTagName('button'); // evt.target is the form
            var clickedId;

            // go through all buttons that are in the form and find one that has data-clicked set to true
            for(var i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(buttons[i].dataset.clicked === 'true') {
                    clickedId = buttons[i].id;

                    break;
                }
            }

            // then you make use of button id
            if(clickedId === 'save-asis') {
               // do something for save-asis
            }
            else if(clickedId === 'save-asis') {
               // do something for save-all
            }
        }
```

Then adjust your html code:

```
    <div class="form-actions" onclick="markClickedButton(this, event)">
        <button type="submit" id="save-asis" class="btn cancel" formnovalidate>Save</button>
        <button type="submit" id="save-all" class="btn btn-primary" >Validate and save</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function markClickedButton(element, evt) {
            var buttons = element.getElementsByTagName('button');
            var target = evt.target;

            // if form-actions 
            if(target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") return;

            // first reset all markers to default value
            for(var i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               buttons[i].dataset.clicked = false;
            }

            // now mark the button that was clicked
            target.dataset.clicked = true
        }
    </script>
```

The code above does the following:
  it adds inline click listener `markClickedButton` to form-actions div. This listener marks a button that was clicked with a data-clicked attribute. Then in `newCaseValidate` you find a button that was used to submit and extract its id.

Comment: Thanks. However, this gives only the ID of the calling form, not the button itself

Answer (score 1):

The `currentTarget` of the event that is automatically passed to your function will give you what button has been clicked.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

```
const newCaseValidate = e => console.log(e.currentTarget)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this gives only the ID of the calling form, not the button itself. Unless I'm using this in the wrong place. I assume that this should be inside the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

For pure js you can use `addEventListener`

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

For jQuery

```
$("button").click(function() {
    console.log(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```